# lost focus on textarea when keyboard appear

Tags: html, ios, keyboard, touch, textarea

I have a web application (not android Application)

I have many textarea in my page like example bellow, if I click on textarea in iPad , the keyborad appear and I lost focus in my textarea.

my question : how can I keep the focus even if the keybord appear? without using jquery mobile.

exemple

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
            <div align="center">
                This is outside the area<br><br>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="myname">
                      Now we are inside the area - which is nice.
                </textarea>
                <br><br>
                And now we are outside the area again.
            </div>
             <div align="center">
                This is outside the area<br><br>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="myname">
                      Now we are inside the area - which is nice.
                </textarea>
                <br><br>
                And now we are outside the area again.
            </div>
             <div align="center">
                This is outside the area<br><br>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="myname">
                      Now we are inside the area - which is nice.
                </textarea>
                <br><br>
                And now we are outside the area again.
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then why you tagged this question with Android tag ?

Comment: remove android tag from question

Comment: because it`s problem related to android

Answer (score 0):

You could try the HTML **autofocus** attribute:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="myname" autofocus>
  Now we are inside the area - which is nice.
</textarea>
```

Not sure if `onclick="autofocus"` works btw. (don't believe it does. you are going to need javascript)